# What is the difference between an empty double integral and an empty surface integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals

Consider the integration of $1$ over the surface of a sphere with radius $r$ which in this case would just be equal to $4\pi r^2$. The notation provided in my textbook looks like
$$\iint_\Omega \,dA$$
where I am unsure of what $\Omega$ is supposed to denote. 
Given $S$ is the surface of the sphere, I am certain that the empty surface integral over $S$ is equal to $4\pi r^2$. I am confused as to why 
$$\iint_S \,dS = \iint_\Omega \,dA$$
for what I believe to be a problem with understanding what these notations mean.

EDIT: This is coming from a physics textbook which I have come to realize abuses notation quite a bit. Thus I think that they actually mean a surface integral when they write 
$$\iint_\Omega \,dA$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When considering the integral
 $
\iint_{\Omega}dA
$:

1. $\Omega$ is the **symbol** for the set of integration boundaries
2. $A$ is the **symbol** which denotes the set of variables to integrate.

In other words they are symbols or **dummy variables** and can be replaced by whichever letter or symbol you prefer, e.g., $S$.

This being said, in some books, there is a little distinction to be made between $dS$ and $dA$. Typically, $dS$ is an **infinitesimal surface**, while $dA$ is an **infinitesimal variation of the parameters that describe the surface**. As an example, consider your sphere $S$ with radius $r$; it can be parametrized as
\begin{cases}
x=r\cos\theta\sin\phi\\
y=r\sin\theta\sin\phi\quad\quad \theta,\phi\in [0,2\pi]\times [0,\pi]\\
z=r\cos\phi
\end{cases}
In this case, $dS\neq dA=d\theta d\phi$. The correct equality is 
$$dS=r^2\sin\phi dA=r^2\sin \phi d\theta d\phi
$$

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the general notation (for any problem) is $\iint_\Omega dA$ where A is the area of your shape and $\Omega$ stands for "The whole surface". In this case, the surface of the sphere is S and "The whole surface" is S as well. I do not see, however, how the notation would differ for a specific problem.